# How to change the color of highcharts series graph to black & white during downloading it as an image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

```
I was trying to download the highcharts.js line graph in the black and white image during downloading in spite of the colors which are randomly generated in the graph. But I am not getting how can I achieve this.
```

Below is the link to the graph.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

I want the graph to be black and white during downloading only and I want them to stay colorful during the rendering. Right now it is downloading as a colorful image. 

Thanks in advance because I am a novice in the highcharts. I am stuck in this position. Please help me out.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? You just linked the Highcharts demo not your code.

Comment: I am not getting how to proceed that is why I had asked this question @core972.

Answer (score 0):

Use the export option to change the default colors to black:

```
exporting: {
        chartOptions: {
            colors: ['#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000', '#000000'],
        }
    },
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/6hgyrq0w/5/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, This is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the colors for exporting by `chartOptions` property:

```
exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
        ...
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8typuasx/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.chartOptions

Comment: Thanks for the support :)